# Jquery load php work into div but not in form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to get data into another INFORM.php file using `<?Php echo $_post['data'];?>` into a `<p>` tag.

As result I get `undefined`, so I am comparing the two codes below but I don't understand why this:

```
<script>
function inform(cx, cy) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var c_x = cx;
        var c_y = cy;
        $("#cont").load("index5.php", {
            cox: c_x,
            coy: c_y
        });
    })
};
</script>
<div id="cont" style='position:absolute;top:100px;left: 100px; border:solid 1px black;width:auto; height:auto;z-index:99;'></div>
```

Works fine, and this one:

```
<script>
function inform(cx, cy) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var c_x = cx;
        var c_y = cy;
        $("#send:input[name='data']").load("index5.php", {
            cox: c_x,
            coy: c_y
        });
    })
};
</script>
<form id="send" style="position: absolute;top:500px;left:20px; z-index: 9999;" action="INFORM.php" method="POST" target="hidden-form">
    <input type="hidden" id="seg1" name="data" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send Data">
</form>
```

does not work.

Comment: Remove document ready handler i.e. `$(document).ready(function () {  });` from your function

Comment: Aside from the incorrect selector in the second example, you cant load HTML in to an `input` element, so I'm unsure what you're trying to do

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have already remove `$(document).ready(function () { });`,but still does not work. 
The main object is to pass index5.php values to inform.php but index5.php work with x,y parameters from index.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is not correct. Currently you are looking for an `input` element with ID `send`

*Use*, remove `:input[name='data']`

```
$("#send"). //For input selector
```

*instead of*

```
$("#send:input[name='data']").
```

Comment: If i change code like this, print the index5.php results instead of submit button to send data to INFORM.php.Thanks